# Searching for a particular phrase in _all fields generates less number of records comparing to do the same thing on small number of fields

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I wanted to search for a particular phrase using elasticsearch on both _all fields and only 2 fields. The phrase is taken from a file listing more than 10000 keywords.: Here is the code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import os, sys
import requests
import json
es = Elasticsearch(['localhost:9200/'])
with open('localDrive\\extract_keywords\\t2.txt') as my_keywordfile:
    for keyword in my_keywordfile.readlines():
      keyword_array.append(keyword.strip().strip("'")) 
with open('LocalFile\\_description_Results2.txt','w',encoding="utf-8") as f:  
  for x in keyword_array:
        doc = {
                        "query": {
                             "multi_match": {
                                    "query": x,
                                    "type": "phrase",
                                    "fields":["title", "description"],        
                                }
    res = es.search(index='xxx_062617', body=doc)
    json.dump(res, f, ensure_ascii=False)
    f.write(("\n"))

f.close()
```

Also, the query that matches _all fields is:

```
                            "multi_match": {
                                    "query": x,
                                     "type": "phrase",
                                     "fields":"_all",   
                                 }
```

Now what happens is that, I get **101 returned record** if I use query **only on title, and description**. But, I only get **100 returned records if I use _all fields**. And if I want to get unique IDs by combining the ids of all records and remove duplicate ones, I see that there are only 86 duplicate records!

**My questions are:**

1. Does using type:phrase works differently if I use _all fields?
2. Should not I get more number of records if I use _all fields?
3. If _all includes all fields including title, and description, then why using _all does not cover all the records that have been returned by querying title, and description?

Thanks,

Comment: What does your mapping look like for the title/description fields? What analyzers are you using? What are some sample query strings?

Comment: @yyssw here is what I have for mapping

 .....
"dataset": {
    "properties": {
     "creators": {
      "type": "string"
     },
     
     "title": {
      "type": "string"
     },
         
     "description": {
      "type": "string"
     },
        
     "types": {
      "type": "string",
                                                "fields":{
                                                    "raw":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}
                                                    }
     },